# MySql, Is it a way to export/import data from date to date?

Tags: mysql

In my way, I just want to export the data of a week and used it to update somewhere else.

I am new to MySql. So, can I do it by the PHP code written by myself or using other software?

Comment: any details on what kind of data it is? and what do you want to update with it?

Comment: Are you trying to export only the data that was inserted (or updated) in the database during a given period? Or to export some data based on a condition that a column's value is within a certain range?

Comment: In my case.I inserted some data in my database,and after a given period,e.g.one week later.I want to export the data I just inserted last week and use the exported file [ the data I inserted myself ] to update somewhere else.  And I'd like to client to update their DB from the exported file via my own web interface.

Comment: Yeah.because the data is update(insert) every day.So the exported data is based on the date I inserted.And the period is from the date I inserted and until one week later.  Thank you very much for helping!

Answer (score 4):

Go to phpmyadmin write the sql select statement where date between from and to. then in the result page below the results n in the section of **"Query results operations"** you will find export button click the button to get the data to be exported.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where), you can use the --where option to limit data ranges:

```
mysqldump -p -u username DATABASE table --where="datefield >= 'start date' AND datefield <= 'end date')
```

There's also the [OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html#id3346252) option:

```
SELECT INTO OUTFILE '/name/of/dump/file' ...
```

otherwise, it's just a matter of building the appropriate query in MySQL, looping over the result set, and dumping the data into a file from which you can extract the data again somewhere else.